# Changing log format of celery worker and tasks in flask application

Tags: python, asynchronous, logging, celery, worker

I want to change the format of logging output for celery worker and tasks. The celery is integrated in a flask application

```
from celery import signals

@signals.celeryd_init.connect
def setup_log_format(sender, conf, **kwargs):
    conf.worker_log_format = """EventName: worker.event | EventID: worker.event_id | TimeStamp: %(asctime)s | Worker: %(processName)s | Level: %(levelname)s | Message: %(message)s"""
    conf.worker_task_log_format = """EventName: %(task_name)s | EventID: %(task_id)s | TimeStamp: %(asctime)s | Worker: %(processName)s | Level: %(levelname)s | Message: %(message)s"""
```

I am simply using this code snippet to change the log formatting. The following output is received in log file:

**Worker main logs**

```
EventName: worker.event | EventID: worker.event_id | TimeStamp: 2022-05-16 13:50:22,527 | Worker: MainProcess | Level: INFO | Message: mingle: searching for neighbors
```

**Worker task logs**

```
EventName: worker.event | EventID: worker.event_id | TimeStamp: 2022-05-16 13:50:59,289 | Worker: ForkPoolWorker-1 | Level: INFO | Message: Sample log
```

I am facing following issues:

1. Why `worker.event` and `worker.event_id` are not getting logged ?
2. I have defined different log format for task based logs which include `task_name` and `task_id`, but it is still coming in log_worker format. What could be the reason and how to resolve the same ?

Thanks in advance.